# Time and work problem found to be hard

Tags: ratio

First pipe passes 4 liters of water per minute less then second pipe. How many liters of water per
minute passes through the first pipe if it fills a 480 liter basin 8 minutes longer than the second
pipe fills a 384 basin?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried putting 4/x.

Answer (score 2):

Say the first pipe fills at a rate of $x$ liters per minute.
Then, the second pipe fills at a rate of $x+4$ liters per minute.

We know that $t=\frac{q}{r}$ where $r$ is the rate of filling, $t$ is the time taken and $q$ is the quantity filled.

So, $\frac{480}{x}=\frac{384}{x+4}+8$

Solve for $x$ by cross multiplying